# Most efficient way to present collections with graph

Tags: java, xpages, tinkerpop

I am rewriting an IBM Teamroom application with graph db. I am wondering what is most efficient to gather and display collections of vertices?

E.g. I have:

```
public JsonJavaArray getProfiles() {
        DFramedTransactionalGraph<DGraph> graph = GraphHelper.getProfilesGraph();
        Iterable<Profile> all = graph.getElements(Profile.class);
        JsonJavaArray json = new JsonJavaArray();
        int count = 0;
        for (Profile profile : all) {
            JsonJavaObject jo = new JsonJavaObject();
            jo.putString("name", profile.getName());
            jo.putString("department", profile.getDepartment());
            jo.putString("location", profile.getLocation());
            json.put(count, jo);
            count++;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

So I can display it on an XPage as followed in a table:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <xp:repeat rows="30"
        value="#{javascript:profiles.getProfiles();}" var="col"
        indexVar="index">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" 
                value="#{col.name}">
            </xp:text>
        </td>
        <td>
        <xp:text escape="true" 
            value="#{col.department}">
        </xp:text>
        </td>
        <td>
        <xp:text escape="true" 
            value="#{col.location}">
        </xp:text></td>
        </tr>
    </xp:repeat>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My profile class:

```
package com.wordpress.quintessens.graph.teamroom;

import org.openntf.domino.graph2.annotations.AdjacencyUnique;
import org.openntf.domino.graph2.builtin.DVertexFrame;

import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.Property;
import com.tinkerpop.frames.modules.typedgraph.TypeValue;

@TypeValue("profile")
public interface Profile extends DVertexFrame {

    @Property("$$Key")
    public String getKey();

    // optional fields
    @Property("Name")
    public String getName();

    @Property("Name")
    public void setName(String n);

    @Property("Department")
    public String getDepartment();

    @Property("Department")
    public void setDepartment(String n);

    @Property("Location")
    public String getLocation();

    @Property("Location")
    public void setLocation(String n);

    @Property("Email")
    public String getMail();

    @Property("Email")
    public void setMail(String n);

    // real edges!
    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasWritten", direction = Direction.IN)
    public void addTopic(Post post);

    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasWritten", direction = Direction.IN)
    public void removeTopic(Post post);

    @AdjacencyUnique(label = "hasWritten", direction = Direction.IN)
    public Iterable<Post> getPosts();

}
```

All pretty "vanilla" and it works fine. Nevertheless I am wondering if I have chosen the correct approach or have I overlooked something (read: make the architecture simpler)?

Comment: Did you check the tinker pop implementation in the OpenNTF Domino API?

Comment: yes, that I am using